# Javascript print JSON Object

Tags: javascript, json

I want to parse this JSON array and print the `salary` so this what I have tried so far
there is nothing logged in the Console

```js
if (data.action == 'SendArray') {
  let invites = data.invites
  const obj = JSON.parse(invites)
  const myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
  console.log(myJSON.salary)
}
```

JSON:

```
{"factioname":"sp-force","inviter":"MohammedZr","salary":5000},
{"factioname":"air-force", "inviter":"Admin","salary":8000}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is JSON Array? Which salary? What is 2 line?

Comment: Also, on an important technical note, there is no such thing as a "JSON Object" (short of [the actual JSON object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON)): either something is JSON, i.e. a string representation of (part of) a JS object and then _it is a string_ and things like `myJSON.salary` make no sense (strings don't have a `.salary` property), or it's literally just a normal, plain, "boring" object. And on a  JS note: never use `==`, always use `===` unless your conditional _only_ works because type coercion.

Comment: You can not use dot notation on `json` files. It works on objects. You Should log `obj.salary`.

Comment: trivial answer: `json = [{"factioname":"sp-force","inviter":"MohammedZr","salary":5000},
{"factioname":"air-force", "inviter":"Admin","salary":8000}]

for ({salary} of json) console.log(salary)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `const myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj)` turns your object back into a string, which you don't want.

I've done some setup to get your data matching your code but the two things you should note are:

1. Iterating through the array of invites using [for .. of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) (you could use `forEach` instead) and
2. Using [deconstruction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to pull out the salary

```js
data = { action: 'SendArray'
       , invites: '[{"factioname":"sp-force","inviter":"MohammedZr","salary":5000},{"factioname":"air-force", "inviter":"Admin","salary":8000}]'
       }
       
if (data.action == 'SendArray') {
  let invites = data.invites
  const obj = JSON.parse(invites)
  for ({salary} of JSON.parse(invites))
    console.log(salary)}
```

Answer (score 0):

`myJSON` is an array of objects. To log in console need to get each object. we can use `forEach` to get each object and then can console log the `salary` key.

```js
let myJSON =[
  {"factioname":"sp-force","inviter":"MohammedZr","salary":5000},
  {"factioname":"air-force", "inviter":"Admin","salary":8000}];
  
myJSON.forEach(obj=> {
  console.log(obj.salary);
});
```